# Plot not showing up for neural network

Tags: r, neural-network

I want to make a neural network plot but R does not give me a result (plot does not appear).

I coded the following:

```
# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-neural-networks-are-used-for-regression-in-r-programming/?ref=rp

set.seed(500)
install.packages("neuralnet")
library(neuralnet)
library(MASS)

data<-na.omit(DE[309:348]) # some financial data with a lot of NAs that I eliminated
data

# Normalize the data
maxs <- apply(data, 2, max) 
mins <- apply(data, 2, min)
scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(data, center = mins, 
                              scale = maxs - mins))

# Split the data into training and testing set
index <- sample(1:nrow(data), round(0.75 * nrow(data)))
train_ <- scaled[index,]
test_ <- scaled[-index,]

# Build Neural Network
nn <- neuralnet(c1 ~ p1 + p2 + m1 +m2 +m3 +m4 +m5 + m6, 
                data = train_, hidden = c(5, 3), 
                linear.output = TRUE)


# Predict on test data
pr.nn <- compute(nn, test_[,1:8]) # 8 -> number of independent variables in the regression equation

# Compute mean squared error
pr.nn_ <- pr.nn$net.result * (max(data$c1) - min(data$c1)) 
+ min(data$c1)
test.r <- (test_$c1) * (max(data$c1) - min(data$c1)) + 
  min(data$c1)
MSE.nn <- sum((test.r - pr.nn_)^2) / nrow(test_)

# Plot the neural network
plot(nn) # everything worked but plot is not showing up.
```

There is no error message.
The console only shows the plot(nn), written as code.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Does `plot.nnet()` work?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the plots open in a separate window and not in the console environment. However, if I delete all existing plots, then use plot(nn), it works. I heard from a developer that this is regarded as some kind of bug in R, which is a bit of a hassle. However, you just need to know it.

The plot is also working with plotnet(nn) as suggested by Pax, which is different in design.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.